# Can we ask questions about Jewish music here?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is there space here for questions about Jewish Music?

Comment: What about Jewish music?

Comment: E.g. what is the song Narim Kosit by Haim Yisrael about?

Comment: More specific later question: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1898

Answer (score 5):

Questions about Judaism are on topic. Questions not about Judaism are not. Thus, for example, "[Where does the tune for birkat hamazon come from?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29450/)" and "[Where did the sing-song chant that Jews often use while contrasting points come from?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28207)" are fine, whereas "[Who wrote Aleh Katan by Avraham Fried?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15468)" and [a question (now deleted) about the song "Yoya"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4994) have been closed as off-topic.